# node.js: HTML form hangs after submit when inserting data into PostgreSQL database

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql

I have recently set up `node.js` using `Express` and I created a simple HTML form using `Jade`. The form is to insert the data in a `PostgreSQL` database. The problem is that when I press submit on the form, everything is inserted on the database, but the `HTML` form is just hanging/lingering, and at some point it stops with `No data received, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Sometimes it also inserts the data twice. I guess this is because the server side does not return a response, but I cannot see how (I am new to `node.js`).

The form has `action="add_device"` which is routed to `routes/add_device.js`. `add_device.js` looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    res.send('Nothing to see here. Move along.');
});

router.post('/', function(request, response, next) {
    var db      = require('../public/javascripts/db/insert');
    var result  = db.insertDevice(request, response);
    return result;
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `insertDevice` function in my `db` module looks like this (it is exported with `module.exports`):

```
// Insert new QA device. Data arriving as a request from a HTML form.
insertDevice: function (request, response) {

    // Input that is verified in the HTML form.
    // Convert to proper format for PostgreSQL query.
    var name        = '\'' + request.body.name          + '\'';
    var ip_address  = '\'' + request.body.ip_address    + '\'';
    var os          = '\'' + request.body.os            + '\'';

    // Input that needs to be verified. Prepare for PostgreSQL query.
    var mac_address;
    var os_version;
    request.body.mac_address == ""  ?   mac_address = 'NULL'    :   mac_address = '\'' + request.body.mac_address   + '\'';
    request.body.os_version == ""   ?   os_version  = 'NULL'    :   os_version  = '\'' + request.body.os_version    + '\'';

    var pg = require('pg');             // PostgreSQL module.
    var td = require('./table_data')    // Database constants.

    var client = new pg.Client(request.app.get('postgreConnection'));
    client.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Could not connect to postgres', err);
        }

        var QUERY = "INSERT INTO " + td.QA_DEVICES.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                    td.QA_DEVICES.COLUMN_NAME           + ", " +
                    td.QA_DEVICES.COLUMN_MAC_ADDRESS    + ", " +
                    td.QA_DEVICES.COLUMN_IP_ADDRESS     + ", " +
                    td.QA_DEVICES.COLUMN_OS             + ", " +
                    td.QA_DEVICES.COLUMN_OS_VERSION     + ") VALUES(" +
                    name        + ", " +
                    mac_address + ", " +
                    ip_address  + ", " +
                    os          + ", " +
                    os_version  + ");";

        client.query(QUERY, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Error running query: ' + QUERY, err);
            }

            console.log('Query performed: ' + QUERY);
            client.end();
        });
    });

}
```

The *'Query performed'* is always logged to console and data inserted into the database, but the form is still hanging. My questions are:

1. Is it the lack of response from the server that makes the form hang?
2. How can I "send a response back" to the front end?
3. Is it possible to route the front end to another page after insertion into the database? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, your request is receiving no response, so it is hanging.
2. In order to send a response, you can either send a blind acknowledgement right when the request is received (that is not dependent upon the success of the query and may be bad practice), or you can send it in the callback.

```js
client.query(QUERY, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                // response.json({status: 'error'});
                response.write('Error');
                return console.error('Error running query: ' + QUERY, err);
            } else {
  
                // You can send json here too
                // response.json({status: 'success'});
                response.write('Success');

            }

            console.log('Query performed: ' + QUERY);
            client.end();
        });
```

3. If you want to go to another page, simply parse the incoming response on the client side and do a redirect. Using json is a good way to carry this out. You can also do a response.redirect(url) on the server side too, instead of sending back data. Have fun

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you for a good answer with pointers to further good practice.